# NameError 'config' is not defined error in Python

Tags: python

I keep on running into the follwoing error

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\FINAL\retail-sales-prediction-master\retail_sales_prediction\main.py", line 82, in <module> 
anchor_date=date(config['anchor_date']), num_days=6)
NameError: name 'config' is not defined
```

Below is the `main.py` file. The error occurs on the following line `anchor_date=date(config['anchor_date']), num_days=6)`

I have the config file as a separate yml file

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import os
import sys
import yaml
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
from retail_sales_prediction.utils.data_loader import readDataStore
from retail_sales_prediction.utils.data_preparation import FeaturePreparation
from retail_sales_prediction.utils.run_model import run_model_lgbm
from loguru import logger

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Retail_sales_prediction')
parser.add_argument(
    '--config-file',
    dest='config_file',
    type=argparse.FileType(mode='r'))
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.config_file:
    config = yaml.load(args.config_file)
    delattr(args, 'config_file')
logger.info("config.yml")

if __name__ == '__main__':
# data_dir = "Location of Data"


data_dir = ("config")

logger.info('Logger started')

logger.info('Loading the Read Data Module')

rd = readDataStore(data_dir)
# Reading the test data
df_test = rd.read_test("/test.csv")
logger.info('Test Data Loaded')

# Read the items data frame
df_items = rd.read_items("/items.csv").set_index("item_nbr")
logger.info('Items Data Loaded')

# Read the stores data frame
df_stores = rd.read_items("/stores.csv").set_index("store_nbr")
logger.info('Stores Data Loaded')

# Reading the training data
df_train = rd.read_train("/train.csv")
logger.info('Training Data Loaded')

feature_prep = FeaturePreparation(df_train, df_test, df_items, df_stores)
logger.info('Start Data Preparation')
(df_2017, promo_2017,
 df_2017_item, promo_2017_item,
 df_2017_store_class, df_2017_store_class_index,
 df_2017_promo_store_class, df_2017_promo_store_class_index) = feature_prep.pre_process_data()

logger.info('Started Preparing Training Data')
X_train, y_train = feature_prep. \
     get_training_data(df_2017, promo_2017,
                       df_2017_item, promo_2017_item,
                       df_2017_store_class, df_2017_store_class_index,
                       df_2017_promo_store_class, df_2017_promo_store_class_index,
                       anchor_date=date(config['anchor_date']), num_days=6)
logger.info('Started Preparing Validation Data')
X_val, y_val = feature_prep. \
    get_validation_data(df_2017, promo_2017,
                        df_2017_item, promo_2017_item,
                        df_2017_store_class, df_2017_store_class_index,
                        df_2017_promo_store_class, df_2017_promo_store_class_index,
                        val_start_date=config['val_start_date'])

logger.info('Started Preparing Test Data')
X_test = feature_prep. \
    get_test_data(df_2017, promo_2017,
                  df_2017_item, promo_2017_item,
                  df_2017_store_class, df_2017_store_class_index,
                  df_2017_promo_store_class, df_2017_promo_store_class_index,
                  test_start_date=config['test_start_date'])

logger.info('Started Training the Light GBM Model')
run_model_lgbm(feature_prep, 
               X_val, y_val, X_test,
               config, num_days=6)
```

Any solution to this, I would appreciate

Comment: `config` is only defined if `args.config_file` is a truthy value. What config do you want to use if `--config-file` doesn't provide the name of a file to load using `yaml.load`?

Comment: One possibility: provide a suitable `io.StringIO` value as the default file-like object for the `--config-file` option so that there's *always* something for `yaml.load` to read.

Comment: There's a pretty obvious formatting error in your code. Indentation in Python is significant!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Indention is okay on my end, the only issue is the one mentioned

Comment: @chepner Further clarification please

Comment: Well, musing about the code on your end is pretty futile, it's the code here that counts. Please make sure you actually provide a [mcve]. As it stands, that obvious error is a showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

`config` isn't defined if `args.config_file` is `None` (the default when `--config-file` isn't provided). If you want to assume that `config` is defined, then you need to provide some appropriate default value, say, an empty `dict`.

```
if args.config_file:
    config = yaml.load(args.config_file)
    delattr(args, 'config_file')
else:
    config = {}
```

Another alternative is to provide an appropriate default file-like object for `config_file` so that you can call `yaml.load` unconditionally. `io.StringIO` is a convenient choice.

```
from io import StringIO

...

default_config = """\
foo: 3
"""

parser.add_argument(
    '--config-file',
    dest='config_file',
    type=argparse.FileType(mode='r'),
    default=StringIO(default_config))

args = parser.parse_args()

config = yaml.load(args.config_file)
del args.config_file
```

I might prefer a custom type that parses a file immediately, so that you don't need to store the config file's name or a file-like object in `args` to begin with.

```
def yaml_config(s):
    with open(s) as f:
        return yaml.load(f)

parser.add_argument(
    '--config',
    type=yaml_config,
    default={}
)

args = parser.parse_args()
config = args.config
```